# How to clear pipenv's cache

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I am trying to run a simple pipenv install command on a project which returns an error with the numpy library. I already ran the `pipenv --clear` command, but when I run:

```
pipenv install --skip-lock --verbose
```

I see:

```
Using cached numpy-1.24.3-pp38-pypy38_pp73-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (16.7 MB)
```

Which I think is one of the things causing errors.

Does anyone know how to really clear cache on pipenv and/or make a clean install of packages?

Also any optimizations with the pipenv lock command are welcome, because that has been putting me behind schedule on a lot of projects.

Comment: Have you tried just to delete the folders in the virtual environment folder?